# Removing folder from Eclipse Build Path locks AD account

Tags: eclipse

When we delete a folder from an Eclipse Java project through the GUI, the user's Active Directory account is locked out.

[image]

Apparently, Eclipse accesses the Internet whenever something is removed from the Build Path. That wouldn't be problem if it were using correct credentials, but it isn't. I checked the credentials under the Proxy settings and they're correct.

[image]

Actually, if they were incorrect, we would not be able to install any of the Marketplace plugins we're using.

I also checked the Windows Credentials manager and don't see any outdated credentials.

Where is it picking up those incorrect credentials? Alternatively, how do we prevent it from accessing the Internet when the Build Path is updated?
We're running Eclipse 4.16 because we have to stick to the 1.8 JDK for now.

[image]

Comment: What is "AD"? Core Eclipse does not access the net when you delete something. It must be an additional plug-in you have installed. Also note that 4.16 is now 7 releases old.

Comment: Also note that although Eclipse itself now needs at least Java 11 it can still run programs with any release of Java. So there is no need to stick with an old release because your code uses Java 8.